# What size ceiling fan lightbulb is this

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan, bulb

I want to replace the bulbs in my ceiling fan with brighter (hopefully LED) bulbs.  I can't find anything that says what type of bulb this is though.  The fixture has the numbers E307732 and 48A8 WG-17 printed on it.  The only thing printed on the bulb is "SEC115-125V40W China".  The bulb diameter seems to be about 1 3/8", and the base diameter is around 9/16" to 5/8" (I'm having a hard time measuring the base).

[image: Light fixture]

Comment: Another name for the E17 base is “intermediate”.   I just tried “fan bulb LED Intermediate” in the amazon search box and found many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to tell in a photo, but looks like an E17 to me.  Smaller than Edison E26, larger than candelabra.  If the base screws are around 17mm, there ya go.

Tricky size to find LEDs in, not impossible but your choices may be limited.

Comment: The designation "WG-17" must mean a 17 mm diameter base: http://www.bulbs.com/Light_Bulbs/Intermediate_(E17)-Base/results.aspx. You could get reducer adaptors (http://www.bulbs.com/product/INTER-TO-CAND-SOCKET-REDUCER?RefId=14) to candelabra which should allow you to use candelabra LEDs.